# How do I access external html elements (not defined in the view) from a cakePHP controller function?

Tags: php, jquery, html, cakephp

I have a set of HTML checkboxes inside of a `form` that are connected to a MySQL database and updated using a CakePHP controller edit function. They are in a modal within my site and not in the view.

When I use the form to make the API call, I'm able to access whether or not the checkboxes are checked with `isset($this->request->data['checkbox_name'])` however, I'm not able to pass through the auth token and therefore can't authenticate.

When I use an AJAX call in my JavaScript, I'm able to pass through the auth token, but can't view the checkbox data.

Is there a way to access the checkbox information while using the JavaScript method rather than the form submit method? I think I could send the set of boolean values through as a message but I'm not sure how.

Comment: use .submit() method from javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "<?php echo $this->base; ?>/controllers/action",
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: { student_id: '5' },
                                success: function(data)
                                {
                                    if(data){


                                    }   
                                }
                        });
```

When receiving a passed data from ajax I used $_POST['student_id'] or $_GET['student_id'], depends on the ajax dataType. You may want to inspect the request first with $this->request->is('ajax'); This may help : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#inspecting-the-request http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-xml-or-json-data